# Saving form data with dynamic checkbox count in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, forms, checkbox

I’m doing an electronic journal of students for notes about visiting. Marks should be put down in checkboxes, and then go to the database in the JSON column.
I insert student data using map.
After clicking Submit, I should get an array of this format

```
[
  { SCHEDULE_ID : ''
    DATA : [ { NUMBER : '1', isChecked : true/false},
            { NUMBER : '2', isChecked : true/false},
            { NUMBER : '3', isChecked : true/false},
            ...
            { NUMBER : EMOUNT OF ELEMENTS, isChecked : true/false}
            ]
    }
]
```

My React code below.

```
<TableBody>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    {schedule_data.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.STUDENT_ID}>
                <TableCell component='th' scope='row' size='small'> {Counter()} </TableCell>
                <Tooltip placement='right-start' title={
                    <img className={classes.photo} src={`${row.STUDENT_PHOTO}`} alt='PHOTO'/>
                }>
                    <TableCell size='small'>
                        <NavLink to="/profile" className={classes.a}>{row.STUDENT_LAST_NAME}&nbsp;{row.STUDENT_NAME}&nbsp;{row.STUDENT_SECOND_NAME}</NavLink>
                    </TableCell>
                </Tooltip>
                <TableCell align='right' size='small'>
                    <Checkbox color='primary' key={row.STUDENT_ID} placeholder={Counter()} name={Counter()} ref={checkbox}/>
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        ))}
    </form>
</TableBody>
```

I tried to make a form and send data to state but got error `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`.

Comment: We will need more than just this code to help you. Please provide us the code that retrieveyour data and send it to the store. Also, what is the error you get ad where/when ?

Comment: I have `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` when i use <form></form>.

Comment: But your code is working as expected ? It's a warning, if you have a list somewhere, you need to add an attribute key with a unique value inside : `<YouChild ...props key="uniqueKeyHere" />`

Comment: It does not render components inside .map. Without <form> it's working well.

Comment: Well it could be because the <TableBody> can only take <TableRow> as children. Try building your table in this way. You could cheat by a much table as you have elements projected by your map.